# How to move an image on a navbar with justify-content: center

Tags: html, css

Here's how my navbar looks like:

```
    <div class="menu" id="menu-toggle">
    Menu
  </div>
  <nav class="manu-nav" id="menu-nav">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/58b061138a4b5bbbc8492951.png" height="45" /></a>

    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Cats</a>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Litters</a>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Toys</a>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">About us</a>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Contact us</a>

  </nav>
```

I am trying to move the image away from the home button, but if I use padding or margin, the whole thing is changing because the navbar has got `justify-content: center;` style, Is there a way to keep the navabar option button centered and move just the logo?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sump51xe/7/)

Comment: you want the logo on the left and the nav links centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can add class for image '.site_left_img' then add css.

```
.site_left_img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, refer to this https://jsfiddle.net/Vadivel123/yrjnxpb0/4/

Comment: Is there a way to keep the image in one place? When i change the width of the page the logo is changing position

Comment: You can adjust left position

Comment: yeah but at one point the logo covers the home button, can I stop it from going over the other `a tags`?

Comment: that time you can change font-size and  padding for a tag

Comment: can I set like a constant margin from the home button, so the image is never going to cover it?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    width: 10%;
 display:inline-block;
}

body {
    
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
 margin: 1%;
    font-size: 2em;
 display:inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
    color: #E6E6E6;

}

nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #214569;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #8C9DBF;
}

/*
nav p {
    top: 0;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
*/

header {
    background-color: #214569;
 opacity:0.7;
}

.socialMedia {
    width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
    color: #7D0CE8;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #fff;
    opacity: .9;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; 
    top: 32%;
    
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
    font-size: 9em;
    color: #7D0CE8;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #fff;
    opacity: .8;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 30%;
}

#secondBackground {
    background: url(img/salad02.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 1400px;
    width: auto;
}

#thirdBackground {
    background: url() no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 1000px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Restaurant HAYQ</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="author" content="Aurimas Ransys">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Armenian Food, Food">
        <meta name="description" content="Armenian Food Business">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes|Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <section id="navbackground">
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <img src="img/hayq.png" alt ="logo" class="logo"/>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="menu.html">Drivers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="events.html">Bolids</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">about us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact us</a></li>
                        <img src="img/media.png" alt="social media" class="socialMedia">
                    </ul>
<!-- Just wanted to add social media on nav bar
                <p>Follow us on<br> social media</p>
-->
                </nav>
            </header>
        </section>
        
        <section id="firstdBackground">
            <h1>HAYQ</h1>
            <h2>Armenian Specials</h2>
        </section>
        
        <section id="secondBackground">
        nothing here
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```